# What is causing yellow leaves on my Morning Glory?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, morning-glory

What's wrong with my Morning Glory? It's grown outside, the temperature has been around 5-10 °C at night and 10-30 °C at day time since I planted them.

Could it be cold, pH, overwatering?

[image: Morning glory with yellow leaves]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please read that similar question. If none of those answers help you, edit your question to show what you need that wasn't covered. If your question gets closed, don't get discouraged. Look  around, you might find something you can answer. Also, if you have more questions, we'd like to see them!